# ServiceStack GetRequestFilterAttributes NullReference

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm trying to use the new API approach for ServiceStack and I'm building a test console application to host it. So far I have the route instantiating the request DTO, but before the request reaches my service's Any method, I get this exception:

```
Error Code NullReferenceException 
Message Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Stack Trace at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Utils.FilterAttributeCache.GetRequestFilterAttributes(Type requestDtoType) at 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.EndpointHost.ApplyRequestFilters(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object requestDto) at 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)
```

Below is my test Service using IReturn and Service (at this point I'm only trying to return hard-coded results to see it working)

```cs
[DataContract]
public class AllAccounts : IReturn<List<Account>>
{
    public AllAccounts()
    {

    }
}
[DataContract]
public class AccountTest : IReturn<string>
{
    public AccountTest()
    {
        this.Id = 4;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AccountService : Service
{
    public AccountService()
    {
    }

    public object Any(AccountTest test)
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    public object Any(AllAccounts request)
    {
        var ret = new List<Account> {new Account() {Id = 3}};
        return ret;
    }
}
```

All ServiceStack references come from NuGet. I get the same error with either route. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to see your AppHost code and the code in your Configure() method. Nothing you provided in the code above stands out. Below is how I would set up a simple Console app using the code/classes you have provided.

**Initialize and Start the ServiceStack AppHost**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appHost = new AppHost();
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start("http://*:1337/");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Listening on http://localhost:1337/ ...");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

**Inherit from AppHostHttpListenerBase and Configure (not configuring anything for this example)**

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Test Console", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
    }

}
```

**Dto/Request classes**

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set;  }
}

[Route("/AllAccounts")]
[DataContract]
public class AllAccounts : IReturn<List<Account>>
{
    public AllAccounts()
    {

    }
}

[Route("/AccountTest")]
[DataContract]
public class AccountTest : IReturn<string>
{
    public AccountTest()
    {
        this.Id = 4;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Service code to handle your requests - URLS: `localhost:1337/AllAccounts` & `localhost:1337/AccountTest`**

```
public class AccountService : Service
{
    public AccountService()
    {
    }

    public object Any(AccountTest test)
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    public object Any(AllAccounts request)
    {
        var ret = new List<Account> { new Account() { Id = 3 } };
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work. For those seeing similar issues, the problem was that my AppHost initializer was not referencing the assembly that contains the service. My solution has two projects and the one containing the AppHost is separate from the one containing the service endpoints. So in my case I had to initialize AppHost like so:  public AppHost() : base("Test Console", typeof(AccountService).Assembly) { }